# Using the function Map, count the number of words that start with ‘S’ in input_list

Tags: python, map-function

I am getting the count as 3 instead of 2 when I am using below code:

```
input_list = ['Santa Cruz','Santa fe','Mumbai','Delhi']

count = list(map(lambda x: x if x[0] == 'S' else '', input_list))
count.remove('')
print(len(count))
```

Comment: You should check what the method you're using does: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (more pythonic and faster):

```py
input_list = ['Santa Cruz', 'Santa fe', 'Mumbai', 'Delhi']
count = len([True for item in input_list if item.startswith('S')])

# btw tests show that the below approach is actually slower
# in comparison it is by an extremely small fraction slower than map
# however it probably takes less space in memory
# count = sum(x.startswith('S') for x in input_list)

print(count)
```

If you really want to do it with `map`:

```py
input_list = ['Santa Cruz', 'Santa fe', 'Mumbai', 'Delhi']
count = sum(map(lambda x: x.startswith('S'), input_list))

print(count)
```

It also is probably better to use the `str` method `.startswith`

Sources:

- [`.startswith` docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_startswith.asp)
- [`sum` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: count is 4 in this and not 2

Comment: @Bhakti that is certainly not correct for the given examples, did you copy-paste the examples because they both show a count of 2

Comment: it is a part of my assignment question and we are asked to use map function to count this and the output is supposed to be 2

Comment: but there is an example with `map` and it returns 2

Comment: yes it is returning 2. can you explain the use of 'sum' in this example. I did not understand this

Comment: well if you were to print out the list of the map `print(list(map(lambda x: x.startswith('S'), input_list)))` then you would see a list of `[True, True, False, False]`, what sum does is count all the values in the given iterable (in this case the `map`) and return the sum of those, now since `True` and `False` represent `1` and `0` accordingly then the list could be shown as this: `[1, 1, 0, 0]` so the sum goes through the list adding those values so `1 + 1 + 0 + 0 = 2`. [`sum` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)